# pass variable from bash into where clause of sqlite3

Tags: bash, sqlite, variables, clause

I want to pass that `$period` variable, as a condition in where clause of `sqlite`:

It will be in a form of:

```
-2 hours 
-1 day
```

..or alike.

So it has blank space in it, and it gets into script through `getopts`,

```
./script.sh -p "-2 hours"
```

Then it gets parsed and sent to function, where I catch it as `$1`.
But when trying to assemble it into that sqlite statement, in place of those `...`, it does not work

```
period="$1"
sqlite3 -noheader domains.db "select domain,email,update_date,updated_on
                                from tbl_whois where last_run = 1 and updated_on > datetime('now', '...', 'localtime') limit $limit" | \
```

How would I be able to do that, tried with all possible cases of `""` and `''`
but without success.

**edit**

just to be clear, variable gets fine, my problem is related to that `space` issue, as I get from SQlite, too many params specified, or `error: near " "`, because it obviously falls apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
datetime('now', '$period', 'localtime')

datetime('now $period', 'localtime')
```

Or just

```
datetime('$period', 'localtime')
```

With those, `$period` would still expand since it's still a part of `""`. Those single quotes are considered literal values and would not affect it.

Comment: The first thing I tried before posting here, was what you suggested. I marked your answer as solution, because you made me think, and then I realized I made mistake elsewhere, changing `limit=$1` to `period=$1` I lost my `$limit` variable which was also used in query, so the query was illegal being `LIMIT ;`. Lost an hour, beacuse of that stupid overseen.